# "Overriding" TypeScript interfaces for extra specificity

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I feel like there is an easy way of doing this that I might just be missing. But basically, given an interface such as this:

```
interface Order {
  type: string;
  additionalDetails: { [detail: string]: any };
}
```

I want to override/inherit the types of this base interface, but is there a way make it so that any interfaces that does so Order only have these 2 properties?

```
// valid
interface Burger extends Order {
  type: 'cheeseburger';
  additionalDetails: {
    ketchup: boolean;
    cheese: boolean;
    mayo: boolean;
  };
}

// invalid
interface Dessert extends Order {
  type: 'icecream';
  additionalDetails: {
    cone?: boolean;
    waffle?: boolean;
  };
  flavor: string;
}

// invalid
interface Fries extends Order {
  type: 'fries';
}

// invalid
interface FriedChicken extends Order {
  additionalDetails: boolean;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if extends is the right way of doing this here, but it's the implementation I've found that at least throws an error if I do something like the `FriedChicken` interface. I think generics might have something to do with it since I would be wanting any Generic such as that it extends or contains the properties of `Order`, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: This is clearly not what Typescript is for. The Order interface is useless, the `extends` purpose is misused. What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: I think I was pretty clear in what I wanted to achieve, and that I was already sure that extend was not the way to achieve what I had in mind. To sum it up though, I want a way to "extend" an interface, that is, to reuse it, but be able to define it with more specificity by overriding certain property types. In my example, `Order` is sort of like a template; any valid interface and "extends" and "overrides" it must have, and only have, both a `type` and `additionalDetail` property that extends the existing type.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I was able to get.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```
interface Order {
  // type: string; unfortunately this type had to change
  type: any;
  additionalDetails: { [detail: string]: any };
}

type Implements<T, U extends T> = {}

// valid
interface Burger extends Order {
  type: 'cheeseburger';
  additionalDetails: {
    ketchup: boolean;
    cheese: boolean;
    mayo: boolean;
  };
}

// invalid
interface Dessert extends Implements<Dessert, Order> {
  type: 'icecream';
  additionalDetails: {
    cone?: boolean;
    waffle?: boolean;
  };
  flavor: string;
}

// invalid
interface Fries extends Implements<Fries, Order> {
  type: 'fries';
}

// invalid
interface FriedChicken extends Implements<FriedChicken, Order>{
  additionalDetails: boolean;
}
```

There is a open Github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24274) that seems to be exactly what you want, basically instead of having a `interface` `extend` another `interface` you want to have them `implement` each other.

This answer is based off a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24274#issuecomment-471435068) from that issue and while it throws a error on additional properties (`Desserts`) it doesn't throw a error on missing properties (`Fries`).

There are additional comments in the Github issue that may give you the capability you're looking for unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to combine them for your use case.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I want, for an interface to be able to `implement` instead of `extend`. After more research, I think I would actually need to use `type` and not `interface` as well, since `type` doesn't allow more attributes to be added after definition.

Comment: After some more experimentation and mangling, I managed to get half of what I wanted. By changing `interface Order` to `type Order`, then changing `Implementation` to `type Implements<T extends Order> = { }`, TS can determine if any interface extending `Order` is missing any properties. However, I cannot get it to limit it to only those 2 properties and further research indicates that the way TS is built for excessive type checking; it will check if an extended interface is missing properties, but won't check if it has extras. I've decided to do just scrap what I was trying to do. Thanks, :)

Comment: Yeah tbh this sounded like the direction you were taking was going to much against the grain of TypeScript's capabilities. Usually, there's another way in TS to accomplish something similar without something so 'hacky'.

Hopefully, they'll add a something like `implements` but I would definitely try something simpler first and see if it works for you :).